# Delete user account from the front end in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a link in the front end for delete user account in my wordpress site.Once the user clicks on that his/her account should be deleted.

In my functions.php page I added a short code for that.

```
function shortcode_del_user_ac (){
add_action('init','prefix_delete_user');
function prefix_delete_user() {
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action']=='prefix_delete_user') {
   include("./wp-admin/includes/user.php" );


       $user_id = intval($_REQUEST['user_id']);
       wp_delete_user($user_id);
       exit();

}
}}
add_shortcode('abc_del_user_ac',shortcode_del_user_ac);
```

and from my front end (i'm using the visual composer) i added a link as delete user account as follows,

```
<a href="[abc_del_user_ac]">Delete account</a>
```

But once i press that link it again redirected to the user's profile, where the  Delete account link is locating at. And the user account is still there. Its not get deleted.

What I have done wrong there?

Comment: All users have admin rights?

Comment: @Tomm: no, only one admin others are just the subscribers

Comment: You are saying // checking admin permissions. and then you say if current user can edit users (which they should not be able to ) then execute code

Comment: @Tomm:oh yes, my bad! thanks

Comment: @Tomm: i updated my question. still the same thing happening..

Comment: what did you change the if statement to?

Comment: @Tomm: I justt removed the admin checking condition

Comment: I am not to familiar with wp but, are you deleting the user or the user id ?

Comment: @Tomm: user account

Answer (score 0):

You want your users to be able to delete their own account.

Thinking not every user should be a admin, your code won't continue since you want a user to be an admin in order to delete their own account.

> if (current_user_can('edit_users')) {
>          $user_id = intval($_REQUEST['user_id']);
>          wp_delete_user($user_id);
>          exit();    }

This should be changed to something user like instead of admin like.

Comment: I updated my question @Tomm. But the problem is still there.it's not deleting my user account..